# isrepeat “is not a member of KeyEventArgs”

Tags: vb.net

Working with VB 2017.
I have a Form populated from “a lot” of TextBoxes. To manage them I originated the following code:

```
    Private enCellBiger As IEnumerable(Of TextBox)
…………………………………….
    enCellBiger = From textbox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                  Where textbox.Name.Substring(2, 8) = "_TextBox"
                  Order By textbox.Name
    For Each BigEnmrtdID In enCellBiger
        AddHandler BigEnmrtdID.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf BigPrvwKeyDwn
        AddHandler BigEnmrtdID.KeyDown, AddressOf BigKeyDwn
        AddHandler BigEnmrtdID.KeyPress, AddressOf BigKeyPrss
        AddHandler BigEnmrtdID.Enter, AddressOf BigEnter
        AddHandler BigEnmrtdID.Leave, AddressOf BigLeave
        AddHandler BigEnmrtdID.DoubleClick, AddressOf Big2Click
    Next
 ………………………………….
    Private Sub BigPrvwKeyDwn(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
      Select Case (e.KeyCode)
        Case Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Tab
                e.IsInputKey = True
      End Select
    End Sub
……………………………………………….
    Private Sub BigKeyDwn(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        Select Case (e.KeyCode)
            Case Keys.Back
                …………
            Case Keys.Tab, Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Left, Keys.Right
                …………
            Case Else 
                …………
        End Select
    End Sub
```

It works as desired.
Now I need to extend **Sub BigKeyDwn**, allowing to trace Key “0” (zero) pressed repeatedly. For this reason, I modified the code as follow:

```
   Select Case (e.KeyCode)
        Case Keys.Back
            ………… 
        Case Keys.Tab, Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Left, Keys.Right
        ………… 
        Case Keys.D0, Keys.NumPad0
            If e.isrepeat Then
               …………
            End If
         Case Else 
               ………… 
    End Select
```

From the debugger for e.isrepeat I get the info “*isrepeat is not a member of KeyEventArgs*”. 
I’m not able to understand and/or to manage. Can anyone help?

Please understand I’m not a specialist of VB

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BigKeyDwn use [KeyEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for e which does not contain a isrepeat property... I'm not sure where you expect it to be. Even [Preview​Key​Down​Event​Args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) does not have it.

Comment: KeyEventArgs is not PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.  Different events, different event args different composition

Comment: "...allowing to trace Key “0” (zero) pressed repeatedly….": to better explain: " when key 0 is held down… "

Comment: @the_lotus. https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.isrepeat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: System.Windows.Input is for WPF not winform which uses System.Windows.Form

Comment: OOPS!!!! Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Would you have any suggestion how can I trace Zero being held down